# Вытянуть из исходного кода сайта значение между тегами

Tags: php, html, синтаксический-анализ

Всем доброго времени суток. Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно средствами PHP вытянуть из исходного кода сайта значение между тегами `<title></title>`?

Answer (score 6):

Любым парсером, например, [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

P.S. Советчиков парсить регекспами - отправлять лесом, далеко и надолго.

P.P.S. Таких вопросов тут по вагону в день, неужели лень пролистать хотя бы за сегодня?

Comment: @klopp, А что Вы против регулярок имеете? Очень интересно послушать.

Comment: phpQuery есть еще ...  тут вот почитать можно http://habrahabr.ru/post/69149/

Comment: @iproger, они либо занимают килобайты, либо не работают. И ломаются в тот момент, когда хоть что-то минимально поменялось. Я уж молчу про то, что не нужно вообще работать с деревом как с монолитной текстовой структурой.

Comment: @Fike, так надо понимать когда использовать какой инструмент. Для данной задачи вполне подходит регулярка, особенно если требуется обрабатывать большой объем данных.

Comment: Регулярки работают, если их грамотно писать. Но неужели никому не кажется жалким, когда для маленькой задачи (вытянуть title сайта) подключается целая библиотека у которой задача кроме парсинга с сайта ещё и спарсить сам CSS-селектор. Это может быть оправдано, когда дофига чего нужно спарсить и регулярки долго и не охото писать.

Comment: тут регулярка подходит только потому-что title один всего на документ. парсеры особенно phpшные тоже очень капризные. (вот появилась мысль сделать библиотеку типа mechanizer, только в качестве краулера зашить в нее биндинги к phantom)

Comment: @flax, я-то понимаю. Нет, мне не кажется жалким писать код, в котором я буду уверен.

Comment: @flax, регекспы в принципе не предназначены для разбора нерегулярных грамматик. Чем быстрей вы это поймёте, тем меньше проблем будете создавать себе же. Решая подобные задачи регекспами вы обрекаете себя на вечные глюки и возню с костылями вместо того, чтобы сразу применить правильный инструмент.

Comment: @eicto, с `<title>` внутри комментария что делать будем?

Comment: @klopp я не  за то чтобы  парсить DOM регулярками, всё зависит от задачи, как я писал уже, парсеры типа того что вы указали очень строгие, и часто падают там, где браузер работает, мир  к сожелению не идеален (по крайней мере в этом контексте) и если у нас известные данные, в которых источник примерно известен, то можно парсить регуляркой, с подходом "никогда регуляркой" можно дойти до того, что будешь писать парсер для шутк типа апачевых логов каждый раз, когда это потребуется (а что ? там тоже можно устроить веселые ситуации). Так что все зависит от задачи.

Comment: Если мне надо посчитать примерную частоту обращений к vhost прям сейчас, я просто напишу однострочник и не буду заморачиваться с его валидностью. Или более близкий случай - найти все файлы в исходнике которые содержат '<title>' а может и вывести на экран - я сделаю grep и что-то типа `perl -p -e 's/^.*<title>([^<]+)</title>.*$/$1/i'` и уж точно не буду делать это с помощью DOM парсера.

а если я хочу очень точную обработку, я как  и сказал выше буду юзать phantom или какой-нибудь похожий симулятор браузера, медленно и надежно.

Comment: @klopp, ну на счёт title в комментарии Вы конечно правы, не думал об этом. Спасибо, выслушал Ваше мнение, теперь оно аргументировано и я удовлетворён. Вероятно перейду на Вашу сторону после проведения некоторых тестов.

Comment: Всегда использую XML для чтения HTML и ещё нужно его предварительно через [tidy][1] пропустить.

[1]: http://www.php.net//manual/ru/book.tidy.php

Comment: Сегодня кто-то title регуляркой ищет, завтра окажется, что в title кракозябры и надо сначала кодировку правильную установить, которая либо `<meta charset="utf-8">`,  либо `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` а послезавтра окажется, что title не задан и надо найти первый <h1>, или <h2>, или <h3> или на худой конец кусок первого параграфа страницы, или найдут <title> внутри <code>.

Все через этот ад проходили. Мою шишку на лбу показать? HTML регулярками разбирают до первой проблемы с семантикой.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev в описанных мной случаях тоже парсер запускаете ? А для поиска строки в структуре javascript исходников, наверное тоже вместо GREP запускаете спец виртуальную машину (которая умеет например объект scope выдать) гоните ее по всем возможным состояниям и ищите в этих состояниях строку ? что вы делаете для исходников на C++ я вообще боюсь представить.

Comment: @eicto, это всё фантазии на тему. Мы не знаем реальных задач ТС. Просто я исхожу из статистики подобных вопросов на хэшкоде: подавляющее большинство их задающих, с задачами, которые описываете вы, не сталкиваются. А если уж человек в состоянии написать однострочник для наколенных целей, знает про `grep -e` и т.д., то спрашивать как вытащить title он не будет :-)

Comment: @eicto, ну зачем то ж я изучал в универе теорию формальных языков :) наверное чтобы писать автомат состояний и парсить JSON в обход json_decode ;) Всему свой инструмент. Простые строки = regexp. Семантический текст в совместимом с XML формате = DOM + XPath или SAX. Интерпретация языковых конструкций = виртуальные машины. Искать title - это поиск в XML, значит XPath.

Comment: И ещё 5 копеек:

>парсеры типа того что вы указали очень строгие, и часто падают там, где браузер работает

Если честно, с PHP-шными парсерам мало работал. Основной инструмент - HTML::Tree и базирующиеся на нём, они у меня перемалывают **от 3 до 8 тысяч** произвольных HTML в сутки, и не первый год. Никаких падений или некорректного парсинга не замечаю, разве что на в хламину кривых страницах, которые и так интереса не представляют (например, вместо разметки вываливается голый PHP етс).

Comment: Вот опять холивар! К чему это всЁ, все показывают как лни модно парсить умеют?. Авито парсите тогда. Человек хочет получить данные скорее всего с конкретного сайта, ему дали варианты. Что выберет то ему и хорошо.

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
   <?php
    function page_title($url) {
        $fp = file_get_contents($url);   // получаем страницу (тут можно по разному даже через CURL)
        if (!$fp) 
            return null;            // Если страницу не получили выйти и отправить указатель на null

        $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches); // Найти title
        if (!$res) 
            return null; // если ничего не нашли выйти и отправить указатель на null

        $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]); // уберем мусор переводы строк
        $title = trim($title);
        return $title;   // Отдадим заголовок
    }
?>
```

А потом вот так:

```
print page_title("http://www.google.com/"); //ну и так пользуемся.
```

Comment: Парсить HTML регулярками - плохая идея: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1688077